# how to delete the message from Message queue using C#?

Tags: c#, msmq

I am trying to develop MSMQ application for receiving the message from client applications.
I am able to create create message queue and able send/receive messages. Now i want to delete the messages once it is read. I didn't see any methods available with MessageQueue Class.Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove messages from a queue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23227194/how-can-i-remove-messages-from-a-queue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a message has been received, it will be removed from the queue. If you're using peek to view messages, you should stop and begin to use the [Receive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y918yfy2(v=vs.110).aspx) method.